# VERY Simple User Login/Profile System for Android

Tags: android, authentication, user-profile

I want to have a user profile system in an app; this app has absolutely no sensitive data.  I know how to do a secure log in as far as protecting the user password/username etc.  But here is my question... once the login confirms that the username/password combo is correct, **can I do this:**

*Use Sharedpreferences to set a login variable from 0 to 1.  When the user logs out, it goes back to 0.
So anytime there is a function in the app that needs to check if the user is logged in, it just checks the state of this preference variable.*

**Is this a secure way of doing it?  Or is there a better way?**

(Normally in PHP I use session variables, not sure what the Android equivalent is.)

Comment: You could try looking into [android.account.AccountManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html)

Comment: Or actually that's probably too complicated for what you want, I just skimmed the question initially.  Using SharedPreferences should be sufficient, or something extremely straight forward would be a `public static boolean logged_on` variable in a global file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use shared preferences, there are too many things that can go wrong, e.g. your app FCs or is killed by Android and has no chance to update them.

You can override the Application class and use a static value, boolean perhaps, to indicate that the user is logged in.

Here's some pseudo code showing how to override the Application.  It's similar to a global variable but don't overdo this and put all your data here ;)

```
public class MyApp extends Application{

    public static boolean isUserLoggedIn = false;
    ...

public void userLogin(){

   MyApp.isUserLoggedIn = true;
   ...

public void userLogout(){

   MyApp.isUserLoggedIn = false;
   ...

}
```

Because the field is static and initialised to false, everytime your app starts, you can guarantee that it's false.  The only way it can ever be true is if it's set in your app in code.

You also need to add the extended class to your manifest:

```
<application android:name=".MyApp" 
  ...
```

Comment: Hey thanks! I'm certainly plus 1'ing this answer.  I will mark it correct as soon as I can implement this! Just a quick question; I've never extended using Application.  I am basically creating a new class that extends that (rather than add it to an existing class). Assuming that this is correct, does the name where you have "myapp" actually have to match my application name?

Comment: You're creating a new class which extends the default Application class. That's what the tag in the manifest is for. Android will instantiate your extended Application class instead of the default one. There is a little more detail you need but a quick Google will show you plenty of working samples you can copy.  The name can be anything legal, it normally makes sense to name it to mirror your app name in some way which aids comprehension. Tip.  Some tutes and samples show the fully qualified class name in the manifest.  This can fail on some versions of Android in weird ways, hence .MyApp

Comment: ok doing quick research I see everything your saying now!  I'm going to just mark this correct since I believe it's what I need.

Comment: Hey for bonus points,  if doing it by your method: how to you save state if you want the user to stay logged in -- in other words, keep the global variable 1 (or true).  I'm assuming it goes back to 0 (or false) when the app is destroyed.  Is this where SharedPrefeences may be used?

Comment: Yep, the value is guaranteed to be false when your app starts.  If you want the log in to be persistent, that's where shared preferences come in.  Good luck